# Every functional on a banach space can be written as a difference of two positive functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

[image]

My question is about the sentence "It follows that $T^+$ is ... linear". I tried writing down the details but it doesn't seem to follow. We want
$$T^+(f-g)=\sup\{T(h): 0\le h \le f\} - \sup\{T(h'):0\le h'\le g\}
\\ = \sup\{T(h-h'): 0\le h \le f, 0\le h'\le g\}$$
Working from the other side
$$ T^+(f-g) = \sup\{T(r-r'): 0\le r \le (f-g)^+\, 0\le r'\le (f-g)^-\}$$
Now set $f^>(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x)>g(x), 0$ otherwise and $f^<(x)=f(x)$  if $f(x)<g(x), 0$ otherwise. We need to be able to write any given $h-h'$ as $r-r'$ satisfying the inequalities. But
$(f-g)^+ = f^>-g^<= f - f^< - g^< $ and $(f-g)^- = g^>-f^<= g-f^< -g^<$ so the restrictions on $r,r'$ are **strictly** worse than the restrictions on $h,h'$ except in trivial cases so I don't see how its possible

Comment: Presumably $f^+ = \max(0,f)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes

Comment: Have you shown that $T^+$ is additive on positive elements?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes

Comment: Ah my second line is wrong

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that $T^+$ is additive on nonnegative functions. Let $f_1,f_2\ge 0$ and $0\le g_1\le f_2,$ $0\le g_2\le f_2.$ Then $0\le g_1+g_2\le f_1+f_2.$ Therefore
$$T^+(f_1+f_2)\ge T(g_1+g_2)=T(g_1)+T(g_2).$$ Therefore
$$T^+(f_1+f_2)\ge \sup_{0\le g_1\le f_1}T(g_1)+\sup_{0\le g_2\le f_1}T(g_2)=T^+(f_1)+T^+(f_2).$$
Assume $0\le g\le f_1+f_2.$ Let $g_1=\min(g,f_1)$ and $g_2=g-g_1.$ Clearly $0\le g_1\le f_1.$ On the other hand as $g_1\le g,$ we get $g_2\ge 0.$ Moreover as $g\le g$ and $g\le f_1+f_2,$ we obtain $g\le \min(g,f_1)+f_2=g_1+f_2$ Thus $g_2=g-g_1\le f_2.$ Summarizing the above:  $g=g_1+g_2$ and $0\le g_1\le f_1,\ 0\le g_2\le f_2.$ Next
$$T(g)=T(g_1)+T(g_2)\le T^+(f_1)+T^+(f_2).$$ As $g$ was aribtrary we get $T^+(f_1+f_2)\le T^+(f_1)+T^+(f_2).$ Thus we got
$$T^+(f_1+f_2)=T^+(f_1)+T^+(f_2),\quad f_1,\,f_2\ge 0. $$
The condition $T^+(af)=aT^+(f)$ for $a\ge 0$ and $f\ge 0$ is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I prove this in my honours thesis. It's been a while since I've looked at vector lattices though. The key observation appears in paragraph 3 of the proof below.

> **Proposition**
> Suppose $V$ is a normed vector lattice, and define the partial order $\le$ on $V^*$ by
> $$f \le g \iff f(x) \le g(x) ~ \forall x \in V_+.$$
> Then $V^*$ is a vector lattice. The supremum $f \vee g$ satisfies, for all $x \ge 0$,
> $$(f \vee g)(x) = \sup \lbrace f(y) + g(x - y) : y \in [0, x] \rbrace.$$
>
> *Proof.* The linearity axioms of vector lattices are straightforward to prove. We only need to verify the given convolution indeed defines a bounded linear functional on $V$, and that this functional is indeed the supremum of $f$ and $g$. The first thing to establish is that the supremum is finite. For any $z \in [0, x]$, we have $|z| = z \le x = |x|$. By the monotonicity condition, $\|z\| \le \|x\|$, and the same can be said of $x - z \in [0, x]$. Therefore,
> $$|f(z) + g(x - z)| \le \|f\|\|z\| + \|g\|\|x - z\| \le \|f\|\|x\| + \|g\|\|x\|$$
> which implies the supremum is over a bounded set, and is therefore finite.
>
> Since this convolution is defined only for positive elements of $V$, we'll have to define it for all of $V$ by first expressing $x$ as the difference of two positive vectors, for example its positive and negative part, then finding $(f \vee g)(x)$ in the expected way: by computing $f \vee g$ on both positive vectors, and subtracting the results. Before we prove the formula is well-defined, we prove the convolution is additive over positive vectors. Suppose $x, y \in V_+$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> &(f \vee g)(x + y) \\
> = \ &\sup \lbrace f(z) + g(x + y - z) : z \in [0, x + y] \rbrace, \\
> &(f \vee g)(x) + (f \vee g)(y) \\
> = \ &\sup \lbrace f(z_1 + z_2) + g(x + y - z_1 - z_2) : z_1 \in [0, x], z_2 \in [0, y] \rbrace.
> \end{align*}
> To prove $(f \vee g)(x + y) = (f \vee g)(x) + (f \vee g)(y)$, we show they are the supremum over the same set. Certainly if $0 \le z_1 \le x$ and $0 \le z_2 \le y$, then $0 \le z_1 + z_2 \le x + y$, which implies $(f \vee g)(x + y) \ge (f \vee g)(x) + (f \vee g)(y)$. On the other hand, if $0 \le z \le x + y$, we need to express $z$ as a sum $z_1 + z_2$, so that $0 \le z_1 \le x$ and $0 \le z_2 \le y$. Let $z_1 = z \vee x$, and $z_2 = z - z_1$. Then $0 \le z_1 \le x$, and:
> $$0 \le z_2 = z - z \vee x = -(0 \vee (x - z)) = 0 \land (z - x) \le z - x \le y$$
> as required. So, $(f \vee g)(x + y) = (f \vee g)(x) + (f \vee g)(y)$.
>
> Now we may prove that $(f \vee g)(x + y)$ is well-defined for all $x \in V$, using the formula $(f \vee g)(x) = (f \vee g)(a) - (f \vee g)(b)$, where $x = a - b$ and $a, b \in V_+$. Suppose $a, b, c, d \in V_+$ and $a - b = c - d \iff a + d = b + c$. Then, from the previous result:
> \begin{align*}
> &(f \vee g)(a) + (f \vee g)(d) = (f \vee g)(b) + (f \vee g)(c) \\
> \iff \ &(f \vee g)(a) - (f \vee g)(b) = (f \vee g)(c) - (f \vee g)(d).
> \end{align*}
> This also implies that $f \vee g$ is additive over all of $V$, since if $x, y \in V$:
> \begin{align*}
> (f \vee g)(x + y) &= (f \vee g)(x^+ + y^+) - (f \vee g)(x^- + y^-) \\
> &= (f \vee g)(x^+) + (f \vee g)(y^+) - (f \vee g)(x^-) - (f \vee g)(y^-) \\
> &= (f \vee g)(x) + (f \vee g)(y).
> \end{align*}
> It is straightforward to establish that $f \vee g$ is positive homogeneous, and that it is therefore homogeneous. To establish $f \vee g \in V^*$, we need to show it is bounded. As we have proven above, for any $x \in V_+$:
> $$(f \vee g)(x) \le (\|f\| + \|g\|)\|x\|.$$
> The same inequality can easily be extended to $x \in V_-$, so replacing $x$ with $-x$ yields:
> $$|(f \vee g)(x)| \le (\|f\| + \|g\|)\|x\|$$
> for any $x \in V_+ \cup V_-$. Therefore, for any $x \in V$:
> \begin{align*}
> |(f \vee g)(x)| &= |(f \vee g)(x^+) - (f \vee g)(x^-)| \\
> &\le |(f \vee g)(x^+)| + |(f \vee g)(x^-)| \\
> &\le (\|f\| + \|g\|)(\|x^+\| + \|x^-\|) \\
> &\le 2(\|f\| + \|g\|)\|x\|
> \end{align*}
> which implies $f \vee g \in V^*$.
>
> Since, for any $f, g \in V^*$ and $x \in V_+$, $f(x), g(x) \in \lbrace f(z) + g(x - z) : z \in [0, x] \rbrace$, we have $f(x), g(x) \le (f \vee g)(x)$. Thus $f \vee g \ge f, g$. Suppose $h \ge f, g$. Then, for any $x \in V_+$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> (f \vee g)(x) &= \sup \lbrace f(z) + g(x - z) : z \in [0, x] \rbrace \\
> &\le \sup \lbrace h(z) + h(x - z) : z \in [0, x] \rbrace \\
> &= h(x)
> \end{align*}
> proving that $f \vee g \le h$, so $f \vee g$ is indeed the supremum of $f$ and $g$. Therefore $V^*$ is a vector lattice.